# Arranging Ancestry siblings by name and integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ancestry

I have a model called `Category`, I can find the siblings of my current category by calling `@category.parent.siblings` or `Category.siblings_of(params[:id])` but as soon as I try to sort either of those requests I get method errors.

If I call `Category.where(:parent_id => @category.parent.id)` nothing shows up but I get no errors.

If I call `Category.siblings_of(params[:id]).sort('name')` I get the error:

```
undefined method `to_direction' for nil:NilClass
```

If I call `Category.siblings_of(params[:id]).arrange(:order => 'name')` it says:

```
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x007fb00de57b70>
Extracted source (around line #21):

18:                 %i.icon-plus
19:         %li.nav-header a neighbour of:
20:         - for neighbour in @siblings
21:             %li= link_to neighbour.name, neighbour, :remote => true
```

I can get this to work fine as long as I don't sort the results at all, but I'd really like to know why sorting the results would bung everything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what's wrong with your `where` query without seeing what's in your model.  But the sort is probably because you're not trying the right methods.  The normal way to sort with mongoid looks like:

```
Category.siblings_of(params[:id]).order_by(name: :asc)
```

Or see the [docs](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html#sorting) for more syntax options.

Comment: That worked great, now I just need to figure out how to have a secondary order by string-to-integer. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not gonna happen in mongo.  Sort them in ruby.  Or convert to integers in mongo.

Comment: How do you convert them to integers in Mongo?

Comment: You should open a new question for this.